# FileNotFoundError in SQL Server Python ML Services

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I use `sql server ML(Python)` and I have this problem when I use the `[Pandas]` library to read the file `FileNotFoundError` occurs 
The Part Of Code:

```py
df=pd.read_csv("C:\User\ussser\desktop\File.csv")
```

##### Error Picture :

[image]

Comment: Where is the file?  On your pc or on the server?

Comment: pc and server are same ;They are not different

Comment: If you just need to import csv, MSSQL had several handlers like [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#bulk-data_file).

Comment: Not . I need to import by Python

Comment: Try double quotes with double backslash: `pd.read_csv("C:\\happy2019.csv", ...)`.

Comment: Unfortunately no . I did a lot of experiments

Comment: python Version 3.7.1 X64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, grant
`ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` access to the Your directory.